# How to check which format is date in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm getting the date in a string and it's not always same format, is there a way to detect what format is that date for example:

If data comes like this 2023-12-03
I want to somehow get output like this "%Y-%m-%d", so I know which format is using. This is just an example format date in the string can come also like this 13/02/2023 and the format would be "%d/%m/%Y"

Comment: Is there a limited number of formats such that you could just try all the possibilities and take the one that yields the most valid-looking answer?  Or are you trying to build a system that will handle unknown unknowns?

Comment: Do you want to _obtain the format string_, or do you want to _parse the date regardless of the format_ as the answers have shown?

Answer (score -1):

You can use `dateutil` to parse it

```py
from dateutil.parser import parse

date_string = "2023-12-03"
date = parse(date_string)

print(date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
```

This code will output `"2023-12-03"` because the input date string is already in the format `"%Y-%m-%d"`.

If the input date string is in a different format, `dateutil` will try to automatically detect the format and parse the date correctly. For example, if the date string is `"12/03/2023"`, the following code will output `"2023-12-03"`